# AngularJS dynamic forms, how to place schema component at required location in html

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I have created following schema using angular schemaform. But i want name to go in div1 and age to go in div2. Please help me out how to do this.

```js
$scope.schema = {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Name",
                    "required": true
                },
            
            
                "age": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "title": "Age"
                }
            }
               
          };
            
          $scope.form = [
            "*",
            {
              type: "submit",
              title: "Save"
            }
          ];
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the guys working on the ASF project. There are 3 ways to go here.

1. As people have mentioned above, one way to go is making custom templates (or decorators as we call them).
2. The second is using the experimental feature [manual field insertion.](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#manual-field-insertion) (Could work well)
3. Third way is a bit more hackish but quick to do. That is to run several instances of ASF with the same schema and model but split the form definition.

JS (simplified):

```
  $scope.schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Name",
        "required": true
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "number",
        "title": "Age"
      }
    }

  };

  $scope.formOne = [
    "name"
  ];

  $scope.formTwo = [
    "age"
  ];

  $scope.model = {};
```

And the html would be something like this:

```
<div id="div1">
  <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="formOne" sf-model="model"></form>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="formTwo" sf-model="model"></form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the second option in the below plnkr link but it is not working  . Anything I miss here http://plnkr.co/edit/5h0SXm?p=preview  .

Comment: Looks like jquery is loaded after angular, loading it before angular makes it work. (This is terrible and should give some sort of warning or something)

Comment: @Dervisevic:- I tried manual field insertion from documentation you have specified but it's not working. Can you please share working example. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @prasadparab Please see this plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/5h0SXm?p=preview. This is what you needed, I guess.

Comment: @Dervisevic The second option would be perfect for me, but it doesn't work in my Ionic app, and I tested it on the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UzNw3uy7EwSHPlxstsQZ?p=preview) and works fine. Any idea why? I should make my own question about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of display using `$scope.form` options

```
$scope.form = [{
        key : 'age'
    },
    {
        key : 'name'
    },
    {
        type : "submit",
        title : "Save"
    }];
```

I hope, this will resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks. But i know how to change the order.
I want to know, how to place that name field in div1 and age field in div2

Comment: @prasadparab    Can I know, why do you want to do that. There are no options provided by angular-shcema-form, we can try some work around like custom made add on to angular-schema-form.

Comment: Sorry i can't share that. You can consider it as a requiremnt.

Comment: @prasadparab Are you looking to generate those tags dynamically or static one. I am confused, where angular-schema-form generates the id based on schema definition.

Comment: the name should go in one div and age should go in second div. I want like this <div id="div1"><input type="text" placeholder="name"></div><div id="div2"><input type="text" placeholder="age"></div>

Comment: @prasadparab Angular schema form will generate the elements using bootstrap-decorator.js and if you inspect the generated element the bootstrap decorator tag will be the same as in form definition. I don't think, you can insert a element in between that, You can change the template if you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you want to do like this

```
<div ng-repeat="value in schema.properties">
<div id="1">
<input type="text" placeholder="{{value.name.title}}" />
</div>
<div id="2">
<input type="Number" value='{{value.age.type}}'/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no. I am generating dynamic form using json. Based on json data components such as textbox dropdown gets generated. I want to place this components in some predefined divs. In my question, name field should go in div1 and age in div2

Comment: Actually your question is bit confusing ..By the way name field is going in id'1'

Comment: no it's not going. I don't want its value to go inside div1.I want like this <div1><input type="text" placeholder="name"></div1>

Comment: it means you want input type='text' with Name field and age with number Am i right ??

Comment: Yes. The entire element should go inside div and not just value

Comment: please have a look on new edits .Is it according to your need

Answer (score 0):

Play with this Plunker snippet: http://plnkr.co/edit/mpZrVO?p=preview

The key line is here in the `<body>` tag of `index.html`: `<form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="model"></form>`. It's best to style each schema/form as one whole to keep UI consistent, instead of two divs.

Make sure to include the correct dependencies in your module.

Here is what the `app.js` looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize', 'schemaForm']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Name",
        "required": true
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "number",
        "title": "Age"
      }
    }

  };

  $scope.form = [
    "*", {
      type: "submit",
      title: "save"
    }
  ];

  $scope.model = {};
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help.Yes, it's good to keep as one whol,, but, i need it like what i have mentioned. name and age in 2 different divs. Can you please help me on that.